# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified:

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to run the code from this [tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-a-deep-learning-caption-generation-model-in-python/). I have placed the code and dataset in the same directory, but still I get the following error.

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-5f5284db0527> in <module>()
     39 # extract features from all images
     40 directory = 'Flicker8k'
---> 41 features = extract_features(directory)
     42 print('Extracted Features: %d' % len(features))
     43 # save to file

<ipython-input-6-5f5284db0527> in extract_features(directory)
     18         # extract features from each photo
     19         features = dict()
---> 20         for name in listdir(directory):
     21                 # load an image from file
     22                 filename = directory + '/' + name

**FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'Flicker8k'**
```

Answer (score 10):

> The system cannot find the path specified: 'Flicker8k'

It complains about not being able to find specified directory. Try to replace relative directory path `directory = 'Flicker8k'` with full absolute path to the `Flicker8k` directory (seems like you are on Windows so something that looks like `C:\myproject\Flicker8k` or if you are on linux `/home/user/myproject/Flicker8k` or wherever that dataset resides). So, make sure to:

- use absolute path instead of realtive
- folder (with correct capitalization) exists
- dataset is actually there in said folder
- access privileges to folder (and files within) are ok

Comment: I followed your suggestion and replaced my path from "directory = Flicker8k " to "directory=C://user//abbas//Flicker8k" and it worked for me.thanks!

Comment: Did not fix the error for me.

Answer (score 7):

For someone comes here having same error.

If you try list folder in `system32`, but python tell you

`FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\'`

That's cause by using `python-32bit`. Installing 64-bit python will solve the problem.

waste one day to solve it

**Best material to explain :)**

https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2012-March/012121.html

[Python does not find System32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41630224/python-does-not-find-system32)

> This is a very confusing point, so even though it's not directly
>       Python-related, I think it's still valuable to discuss it again.
>
> As you discovered, Windows is helping you.  For reasons that have never
>       been adequately explained to me (and believe me, I have asked people who
>       ought to know), on a 64-bit system, all of the 64-bit commands and DLLs
>       live in \Windows\System32.  All of the 32-bit commands and DLLs live in
>       \Windows\SysWOW64.  A 64-bit process gets to see both of those
>       directories as they really are.
>
> But for a 32-bit process, the operating system "helpfully" rewrites your
>       paths.  When you refer to \Windows\System32, the system helpfully
>       rewrites that reference to \Windows\SysWOW64.  Microsoft calls it file
>       system redirection".  I call it "file system stupidity".
>
> Most of the time, that's OK.  Most of the important commands are present
>       in both directories.  A few (like nbtstat) are not, and that's a problem.
>
> There are two solutions.  One is to use 64-bit Python, which you have
>       said is a problem for you.  The other is to use an API with the
>       tongue-twisting name Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection.  Here is my script:
>
> ```
>    import ctypes
>     k32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32
>     wow64 = ctypes.c_long( 0 )
>     k32.Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection( ctypes.byref(wow64) )
>     # ... do stuff with real files ...
>     k32.Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection( wow64 )
> ```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using an environment, and don't want to change all the paths in your code, then do this at the top:

```py
import os
os.chdir('<path URL>')
```

eg.

```py
import os
os.chdir('C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/projectfolder')
```

Comment: This fixed the error for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes 'file not found' error occurs because the filepath is too long.  You can solve this by adding `"\\\\?\\"` to your filepath; for example + `"\\\\?\\" + os.path`

Comment: Thanks that was the issue. Windows paths are limited 260 chars, I've got more than that. Adding `"r\\?\C:\Users\...` fixed it.