# fined directory in Jupiter notebook

Tags: python, database, download, load, sar

i have code for classification Sar target

```
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
import numpy as np
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Model
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
```

---

```
train_data_dir = '..\\data\\train'
validation_data_dir = '..\\data\\test'
```

---

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_height, img_width),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical')
```

when the run! i have blew error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '..\\data\\train'
```

help meeee

Answer (score 0):

Looks like someone else had the same situation and solved it by installing 64-bit Python, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60612077/14328644.

Comment: tanks but not do